# Installing React Native environment on MacOS Catalina 10.15.3

Tags: ios, reactjs, macos, native, macos-catalina

I would like to create iOS build of React Native application.
I have access to not so new iMac with newest possible version of MacOS Catalina 10.15.3.

I had problem with downloading Xcode for it, and I solved this issue but I can't download Command Line Tools for it.
Is it possible to download Command Line Tools for older version of Xcode (11.3) and setup environment for building iOS app on this MacOS version in 2022?

Comment: here you can see the correct version of xcode https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/

Comment: and here you can download the older versions of xcode and CLT https://developer.apple.com/download/all/

Comment: the version of CLT is the same number of xcode version, in my case, the last version for Catalina 10.15.7 is 12.4 for xcode and CLT.

Comment: here, my problem is with watchman, I'm trying to solve it.